# WebDataRocks - How do I hide the "hamburger" field list menu?

Tags: webdatarocks

Nice product.
In WebDataRocks angular, how do I hide the "hamburger" field list menu?

[image]

I tried CSS overrides
`:host .wdr-fields-view-wrap { position: absolute; z-index: -4; }`

Answer (score 1):

To hide the field list menu, you can set the `configuratorButton` option as `false` inside the `options` object:

```js
const pivot = new WebDataRocks({
  container: "#wdr-component",
  toolbar: true,
  height: 400,
  report: {
    dataSource: {
      type: "csv",
      filename: "https://cdn.webdatarocks.com/data/data.csv"
    },
    options: {
      configuratorButton: false
    },
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.webdatarocks.com/latest/webdatarocks.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.webdatarocks.com/latest/webdatarocks.toolbar.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.webdatarocks.com/latest/webdatarocks.js"></script>

<div id="wdr-component"></div>
```